# sql query: count the number of subjects enrolled by each student

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: subject and student.
I'm trying to count the number of subjects enrolled by each student. How do I do that? I'm trying the code below but it doesn't give the answer I need.

```
SELECT COUNT( subject.SUBJECT ) , student.IDNO, student.FIRSTNAME, subject.SUBJECT
FROM student, subject
GROUP BY subject.SUBJECT
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do have an Enrolment table too, don't you? to resolve the many-to-many relationship between student and subject. you could work with just that. say, your enrolment table has studentID and subjectID columns, then you would only need:

```
SELECT studentID, COUNT(*) FROM Enrolment GROUP BY studentId;
```

or, to include their names too,

```
SELECT s.firstname, COUNT(*) FROM Enrolment e JOIN student s on e.studentId=s.IDNO GROUP BY e.studentId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a join condition. Somewhere you are storing info about what subject each student is taking.  Perhaps `WHERE subject.student_id = student.id`.